# Scala: Higher order function to return the union of sets

Tags: scala, functional-programming, user-defined-functions, higher-order-functions

I am working on the following scala higher order function:

```
def after(M: Set[Expression], n: String): Set[Set[Expression]] = { M.map((expr: Expression) => aft(expr,n)) }
```

The function aft has the following signature:

```
def aft(m: Expression, n: String): Set[Expression]
```

The type `Expression`is an abstract class which I created.

I want the method `after` to take a set M of `Expression`s, apply the `aft` on each element in M and then return the union of the results (i.e. a `Set[Expression]` rather than a `Set[Set[Expression]]`). I think that a higher order function should be used in this case but I can't really understand how to do it as I still consider myself a novice in Scala and functional programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `flatMap` instead of `map`:

```
def after(M: Set[Expression], n: String): Set[Expression] = { M.flatMap((expr: Expression) => aft(expr,n)) }
```

In general for any user defined type to behave as expected with `Set[A]`, one needs to make sure `hashCode` and `equals` are properly implemented, otherwise equality between two objects will use `Object.equals`, which is usually not what you want.

As a side note, although this is a lovely method, it isn't a higher order function. It doesn't take a function as an argument and doesn't return a function.

Comment: I tried that but since I'm working with my own Expression class it won't work. Is there a way how I can implement my 'own' flatmap?

Comment: @wirdis You don't need your own `flatMap`, what you need is to implement `hashCode` and `equals` on `Expression` or it's inheriting children for `Set` to properly work.